# Combine duplicate ID with unique row detail using QUERY/ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem with trying to change the set of data in a Google Sheet to another layout.

I had tried VLOOKUP, QUERY but still cannot solve my problem. I know there is a ARRAYFORMULA but I never used it.

This is my raw data.

| ID | Title | Data Type | Type | Detail | Breed Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | Main | Name | Meow |  |
| 1 | Cat | Main | Breed | She has fluffy hair. | Persia |
| 1 | Cat | Sub | Name | Meow |  |
| 1 | Cat | Sub | Breed | TBA | Persia |
| 2 | Dog | Main | Name | Bok |  |
| 2 | Dog | Main | Breed | Handsome boy | Akita |
| 2 | Dog | Sub | Name | Bok |  |
| 2 | Dog | Sub | Breed | TBA | TBA |
| 3 | Dog2 | Sub | Name | Rob |  |
| 3 | Dog2 | Sub | Breed | TBA | TBA |

I would like to change it to look like this.

| ID | Title | Name | Breed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | Meow | Persia She has fluffy hair. |
| 2 | Dog | Bok | Akita Handsome boy |
| 3 | Dog2 | Rob | TBA TBA |

Breed Type always empty if the Type is not Breed.

The Main in Data Type will take control of the data in each ID. If there is no Main, it will use Sub instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX({SORTN({A2:B, E2:E}, 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(SORTN(A2:A, 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 
 FILTER({A2:A, F2:F&" "&E2:E}, D2:D="breed"), 2, ))})
```

[image]